# React withRouter How to avoid re-render component?

Tags: reactjs

In this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ovomwoompq the hello component gets rerender every time i click on it. This is not very efficient. How can i prevent mycomponent to not rerender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can restict re-render with shouldcomponentUpdate lifecycle method.
Compare old props or state to new if there's no change, dont re-render.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.value != nextState.value;
// or compare props
}
```

This would restrict re-render everytime.

Or using a custom hook for Func Components.

Witre a custom hook like

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

For Typescript

```
const usePrevious = <T extends {}>(value: T) => {
  const ref = useRef<T>();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};
```

and use  useEffect as ,

```
const ABC = (props) => {
    const {propOne, propTwo } = props
    const prev = usePrevious({propOne, propTwo});
    useEffect(() => {
        if(prev.propOne !== propOne) {

         // process here
        }
        if(prev.propTwo !== propTwo) {

         // process here
        }
    }, [propOne, propTwo])
}
```

Comment: But what if i have a function component?

Answer (score 0):

Stopping re-render will make your code more complicated and harder for maintaining. What if you replace active `NavLink` with something else so it would not trigger navigation?

```
import {matchPath} from "react-router";
const routes = {
 hello: {
  path: "/hello",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
 }
};

(!matchPath(this.props.location.pathName, routes.hello) && (
  <NavLink {...routes.hello} to={routes.hello.path}>Hello</NavLink>
))
(matchPath(this.props.location.pathName, routes.hello) && <span ...)
```

PS imo I'd leave it as it's now, extra re-render after explicit click is barely performance bottle-neck